# In Linux, how to find files with modification dates NOT older than a given file?

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, listener, timing

According to GNU, it seems like the modification date is only exact to second level. I have a very high speed system that generates lots of files to a directory (at millisecond rate). I am trying to monitor the new files generated, and display the filenames to the terminal.

Currently, I am using

```
touch .file
sleep 1
find -type f -newer .file
```

to find files that are modified after `.file` was created. However, since the system is running at very high frequency, the `-newer` option in `find` seems not able to catch files that are modified/created at same "time" (exact to seconds) as newly `touched` `.file`. To elaborate what I mean, say I touched the file at `01:02:03 AM`, a new file is generated at `01:02:03:02 AM` (02 milliseconds after the `.file`). `find` will ignore the millisecond, and concludes that they are created at the same time. As a result, this new file is not `newer` than `.file`, hence ignored.

What is a way around? I am thinking of using `! -older`, unfortunately `find` doesn't have such option. I want to avoid writing my own version of `find` to save code size. Any suggestions?

Comment: What about `-not`?

Comment: Modification times aren't and shouldn't be treated as atomic transaction IDs.   Could you move/rename processed files so you always know which ones are pending?

Comment: @thatotherguy I really like this idea. Unfortunately, those files should be stayed read-only. Is there other way to "mark" the files without touching them?

Comment: You could touch dummy files in a different dir or with a different extension, e.g. `for file in *; do if [[ -f ~/processed_files/$file ]]; then echo "Already processed"; else process "$file"; > ~/processed_files/$file; fi; done`.

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to generate filenames with an id and use a `find`´s filter based on it.

Back to your question, you could try this:

```
touch .file
find . -type f -printf "%T@ %p\0" |\
  awk -v RS="\0" -v reftime=$(find . -name .file -printf "%T@") \
      '$1>=reftime {print substr($0,index($0," ")+1)}'
```

`%T@ %p\0` prints the last modification time in seconds since Jan. 1, 1970, 00:00 GMT, with fractional part. It is followed with a space and the filename of the file.

`\0` is used as separator for more safety: the command won't break when filenames contain special chars  `\n` `"` etc.

`awk` is used to compare the last modification times and prints filenames with last modification times newer than or equals to the last modification time of `.file`

Thanks to `printf` each record is `time` +  + `filename`. Naturally, `$1` will be the first field: the last modification time.

In my test on my debian `%T@` times have a fix length. I could replace `index($0," ")+1` with `22`

On my debian the fractional part is always 0 (maybe a precision issue), so in my case all files with last modified time in the same second as `.file` will be printed: even those that are created a little bit before `.file` within the same second.